# why gdaldem is not producing any result?

Tags: gdal

I have a geotiff file with class values (0, 1,  2, 3, and 4).
I want to show each class as different rgb color.

So, I created the text file (color_relief.txt) which contans the following:

```
0 55 78 94
1 98 23 64
2 112 35 99
3 34 67 72
4 78 250 60
```

Then I run the following code using python:

```
import subprocess
in_file =  'single_band.tif'
text_file = 'color_relief.txt'
gdaldem = 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\gdaldem.exe'
out_file =  'result.tif'
subprocess.call([gdaldem ,'color-relif',in_file,text_file,out_file,'-exact_color_entry','-b','1'],shell=True)
in_file, out_file = None, None
```

Unfortunately, no result file is obtained.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Run the gdaldem command in the command line so you can see any error message. Looks like you have a typo in your 1st argument "color-relif".

Comment: @Luke the command prompt just blinks and goes, is it possible to make it to wait?

Comment: @Luke I got FAILURE:Missing valid subutility mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your command  - the 1st argument should be "color-relief" not "color-relif".